# Glitches when using webAudio API with javascript for browser

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I am having issues with using the webAudio API with javascript.

The problem is that I am hearing glitches on the sounds being played in my browser even though I have used a gainNode to gradually increase/decrease the sound when it starts/stops.

The audio file is simply 60 seconds of 400hz tone to demonstrate the issue. In the demo I play a snippet from time point 2.0 seconds for 1 second duration, within this duration I ramp up for 100ms and at 800ms I begin to ramp down for 199ms. This is an attempt to avoid a non zero crossing glitch. I use gainNode.gain.setTargetAtTime() but also tried exponentialRampToValueAtTime() as well. In this example I repeat at time point 52 seconds.
At the beginning of the code I impliment an audioContext.resume() to trigger the audio facility of the browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My experiment</title>

    <audio id="audio" src="pure_400Hz_tone.ogg" preload="auto"></audio>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="jspsych_target"></div>
    <button onclick="dummyPress()">Press to Activate Audio</button>
    <button onclick="playTheTones()">sound the tone</button>
  </body>

  <script>
  console.log("setting up audiocontext at ver 28 ");
  const audioContext = new AudioContext();
  const element = document.querySelector("audio");
  const source = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(element);
  const gainNode = audioContext.createGain();

  gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(0, audioContext.currentTime);
  source.connect(gainNode);
  gainNode.connect(audioContext.destination);

  function dummyPress(){
    audioContext.resume();
    playTheTones();
  };


  function playTheTones(){

    // ******* The First Tone ***********
    // **********************************
       source.currentTime = 2;
       gainNode.gain.setTargetAtTime(1.0, audioContext.currentTime, 0.1);

       var g = setTimeout(function(){
         gainNode.gain.setTargetAtTime(0.0001, audioContext.currentTime, 0.199);
         console.log("start Down @   " + source.currentTime);
       },800);

       source.mediaElement.play();

       console.log("PLAYING 2 now @   " + source.currentTime);
       var k = setTimeout(function(){
         source.mediaElement.pause();
         console.log("STOPPED @   " + source.currentTime);
       },1100);

       // ******* The Second Tone ***********
       // **********************************
       setTimeout(function(){
         source.currentTime = 52;
         gainNode.gain.setTargetAtTime(1.0, audioContext.currentTime, 0.1);

         var h = setTimeout(function(){
           gainNode.gain.setTargetAtTime(0.0001, audioContext.currentTime, 0.199);
           console.log("start Down @   " + source.currentTime);
         },800);

         source.mediaElement.play();

         console.log("PLAYING 52 now @   " + source.currentTime);
         var j = setTimeout(function(){
           source.mediaElement.pause();
           console.log("STOPPED @   " + source.currentTime);
         },1100);
       },1500);

  };


  </script>
</html>
```

Unfortunately I think I have confused myself in trying to resolve the glitch issues and may not be using best practice using the API and this might be causing my problem.

Would someone look at the code and point out if I am using the API correctly and confirm that I am correct in thinking I should be able to use the API and present tones in this way without glitching.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem

```
gainNode.gain.setTargetAtTime(0.0001, audioContext.currentTime, 0.199);
```

the third parameter is a 'time constant' not a 'time duration' so it was mammothly large at 0.199 and the gain did not diminish rapidly enough so causing the glitch. Setting to 0.01 cures the issue !